# Extending internal General Link dialog with Checkbox in SPEAK

Tags: speak

I followed these instructions to [add a text field to the internal General Link dialog](https://drazenjanjicek.com/2016/03/18/extending-sitecore-8-1-adding-support-for-anchors-in-internal-links/) which works fine.

But now I need a checkbox instead of a text field (anchor) but it still should add a tag with text in the link field like this in raw value view (data-name="teaser_a"):

```xml
<link text="Test" data-name="teaser_a" linktype="internal" class="" title="" target="" querystring="" id="{819BFAC1-A563-49DA-9C2C-E88D0B397618}" />
```

while `teaser_a` is the item name, which should automatically be added.

So instead of `textbox rendering` I would add a **checkbox rendering** to `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs/InsertLinkViaTreeDialog` layout.

But after that I'm not entirely sure. I'll probably have to update the `ReadQueryParamsAndUpdatePlaceholders` method in `InsertLinkDialogTreePageCode` class and somehow get the item name.

The code in the example looks like this:

```cs
private void ReadQueryParamsAndUpdatePlaceholders()
{
    Original implementation
    {
        this.Anchor.Parameters["Text"] = GetXmlAttributeValue(element, "anchor");
    }
}
```

And than respectively alter the rule in `MakeInternalLinkFromTreeView` since it is not a `textControl` anymore. Code in example:

```
 ... anchor target name to [targetAnchorID,,,textControl6]'s text property ...
```

I'm new to SPEAK and the rule engine. Can someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Gatogordo - I've implemented this general link textbox in our solution too but not as a checkbox as you've mentioned. I've not got that much experience with speak + rules engine I'm afraid even though I've built a speak app I didn't build it with binding like this via the rules engine. It's quite complicated I feel. Are you just trying to add an additional checkbox then to go below your textbox?

Comment: I wanted to make it easy for the author. When the checkbox is checked the additional attribute will be populated all by itself. But since it is such a pain, I'll stick to the text box and we have to tutor the author what to put in there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought... Add a hidden textbox as described in the blog post and populate/clear it when the checked state of the checkbox changes. The other way around, check the checkbox if the hidden textbox isn't empty.

Comment: It's been a while since we developed this feature so I won't change it now. But good idea. Thank you.